How to override TierPriceBox.php?
I would like to override vendor/magento/module-configurable-product/Pricing/Render/TierPriceBox.php in my extension, but failed to do so so far.
So, how can I override that class?
Thanks!

You can add this code into your module :
Create the di.xml file into your module Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<preference for="Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Pricing\Render\TierPriceBox" type="Vendor\Magento\Pricing\Render\TierPriceBox" />
</config>

Create the TierPriceBox.php file in following path Vendor/Module/Pricing/Render/TierPriceBox.php
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Vendor\Module\Pricing\Render;

use Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Price\TierPrice;

/**
 * Responsible for displaying tier price box on configurable product page.
 */
class TierPriceBox extends \Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Pricing\Render\FinalPriceBox
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function toHtml()
    {
        // Hide tier price block in case of MSRP or in case when no options with tier price.
        if (!$this->isMsrpPriceApplicable() && $this->isTierPriceApplicable()) {
            return parent::toHtml();
        }
        return '';
    }

    /**
     * Check if at least one of simple products has tier price.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    private function isTierPriceApplicable()
    {
        $product = $this->getSaleableItem();
        foreach ($product->getTypeInstance()->getUsedProducts($product) as $simpleProduct) {
            if ($simpleProduct->isSalable() &&
                !empty($simpleProduct->getPriceInfo()->getPrice(TierPrice::PRICE_CODE)->getTierPriceList())
            ) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}


Thats working, thanks!
